# Torus action on a prime divisor of Toric Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Let △ be a fan, X(△) be a toric variety and D be a prime divisor of X(△).
Let Tn be a torus and t∈Tn. Then why is t*D a prime divisor of X(△)?

Comment: Because $t \colon X \to X$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Thank you. Then why is t an topological isomorphism? Is Tn×X(△)→X(△) a continuous group action? I introduce the product topology into Tn×X(△).

Comment: What is your definition of toric variety? And please, type with tex, otherwise it is hard to read your questions.

Comment: Let $N$ be a lattice. Let $M$ be $Hom_{\Bbb Z}(N,\Bbb Z)$. 
Let $\Delta$ be a fan in $N$.
Let $\sigma$ belong to $\Delta$.
Let $U_\sigma$ be an affine scheme $Spec\Bbb C[S_\sigma]$,  where $S_\sigma$ is $\sigma^\vee \cap M$. 
Then we construct $X(\Delta)$ by glueing $U_\sigma$.
Let $T_N$ be an affine scheme $Spec \Bbb C[M]$. 
\begin{align*}
& S_\sigma \ni u \rightarrow (u, u) \in M \times S_\sigma \\
& \Bbb C[S_\sigma] \rightarrow C[M\times S_\sigma]=C[M]\otimes_{\Bbb C}\Bbb C[S_\sigma] \\
&Spec \Bbb C[M] \times_{\Bbb C} Spec \Bbb C[S_\sigma] \rightarrow Spec \Bbb C[S_\sigma] \\

Comment: & f_\sigma : T_N \times_{\Bbb C} U_\sigma \rightarrow U_\sigma
\end{align*}
By glueing ${\Bbb C}$ scheme morphisms $f_\sigma$, we define 
$T_N \times_{\Bbb C} X(\Delta) \rightarrow X(\Delta)$. This morphism induces 
$T_N(\Bbb C)\times X(\Delta)(\Bbb C)\rightarrow X(\Delta)(\Bbb C)$.

Is $T_N(\Bbb C)\times X(\Delta)(\Bbb C)\rightarrow X(\Delta)(\Bbb C)$ continuous?,
where $T_N(\Bbb C)\times X(\Delta)(\Bbb C)$ is a topological 
product.

Comment: Usually a toric variety is defined as an algebraic variety endowed with a faithful quasitransitive **algebraic** action of a torus, and a description by means of a fan is a classification result.